# i want to get every <path> where <id_wert> = 1 from a xml file

Tags: xpath

i want to get every `<path>` where `<id_wert>` = 1 from a xml file

my query in sql would be "select **path** from xml where **id** = 1

```
<xml_export>
      <id>1<\id>
      <path>\DATEN\00000001.003</path>
</xml_export>
<xml_export>
      <id>2</id>
      <path>\DATEN\00000001.004</path>
</xml_export>
<xml_export>
      <id>1</id>
      <path>\DATEN\00000001.005</path>
</xml_export>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate `xml_export` parent nodes by child `id` with desired value and then to get their child `path` nodes.
As following:

```xml
"//xml_export[.//id='1']//path"
```

In case you want to make it more strict, to search for only cases where `id` and `path` are direct children of `xml_export` the former expression can be changed to be

```xml
"//xml_export[./id='1']/path"
```